# Button add to cart in .tpl of my module on Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, smarty

I want to add a button "Add to cart" in my module on Prestashop 1.6.

How to do this please ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button add to cart with ths code:

```
<form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post" id="add-to-cart-or-refresh">
  <!-- hidden -->
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product.id}" id="product_page_product_id">
  <!-- variants, only use if you plan to have variants -->
  {include file="catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl"}
  <!-- qty -->
  <input
    type="text"
    name="qty"
    id="quantity_wanted"
    value="1"
    class="input-group"
    min="1"
    max="9"
    aria-label="{l s='Quantity' d='Shop.Theme.Actions'}"
  >
  <!-- submit -->
  <button
    class="btn btn-main add-to-cart"
    data-button-action="add-to-cart"
    type="submit"
  >
    Add to cart
  </button>
</form>
```

A click on this button will automatically trigger an ajax call to update the cart with the product represented by the input `name="id_product"` and the quantity from the input `name="qty"`.

`static_token` comes from `'static_token' => Tools::getToken(false),`, here https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L512

If you want to add variants, you should use PS's standard way:
[image]

see `catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl` in https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/master/themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl

Comment: Thanks but I want to call a function of my controller (php file in module directory) to put the product in the cart. Do you know how to do this ?

Comment: why do you want to do it server-side and not client-side? How are you calling this function? Please provide some context in your initial query :)

Comment: I'm a novice on module development on PS. I display with my custom module page, product's information selected by the customer. After, I suggest to personnalize this product with a new price calculated. After that, I want to permit to the customer to add to cart this product personnalized.

Comment: ok, but how do you call this function? Why the button in html doesn't fulfill your requirements? thanks

Comment: I don't know how to add this product on cart. That's my question ^^

Comment: edit your initial question by adding your actual html, with your personnalization fields

Comment: It's very long :/ My html contains inputs radio fields. Customer select his choices, and, bases on selected fields, my javascript calculate a new price. Now, at the bottom of my html, I want to permit to add the product in cart. I want to use native customization field of Prestashop to save a string that contain all the choices of my customer.

Comment: see my edited answer, your personnalization fields should come from the variants template